# Azure Portal Issue/ARM Template/Service Bus

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

Experiencing an issue when creating a service bus relay that has hybrid connections via ARM template results in a portal issue. Any ideas? The deployment operations shows success, and no issues when provisioning the service bus relay.

[image: Azure Portal Issue Screenshot]

Comment: you probably want to message support about this, really doubt you can get help here unless somebody from MS stumbles upon this

Comment: If you haven’t done this already, try clearing browser history, cookies and cache. Test this on another browser or InPrivate mode. Also, sign out and re-login to the Azure Portal then try.